# Can I use the Karma / Jasmine testing framework in Angular 4 to test appearance of Bootstrap modals and tooltips?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-components

I don't think this is a very constructive question on StackOverflow, or I think this is more of an opinionated one. But since this is related to programming tools and is somewhat a practical, answerable problem, I'll ask anyway.

I can't share any source code right here, but what I got are three Angular 4 components where two of them use [Bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), and one uses [Bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/). I want to write test code on their spec.ts files using the [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io) and [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/index.html) testing frameworks, as the [Angular documentation says](https://angular.io/guide/testing), *to make sure that the modals do display when I click on some buttons, and the tooltips display when I simulate a mouse hover event on span elements that trigger them.*

From doing some research on my own, including some StackOverflow questions I found myself, I did see some that talk about testing components to make sure that modals do open up correctly, but I didn't see any questions about testing to see if the tooltips do show up and have the right text. In addition, I saw one source where using the testing frameworks Angular provides is really meant to test the functionality of the components themselves, mainly the controllers, and not the rendered views themselves.

This leaves me with this: **Are Jasmine and Karma really meant to test only the functionality of the Angular 4 components I wrote myself and not the look and feel of them nor the use of any third-party libraries used such as Bootstrap? If no, how do I use them to test appearance of modals and tooltips?**

Answer (score 0):

You can test components functionality, and check if template changes. For theses purposes in Jasmine we have **fixture.detectChanges()**.
https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing

For testing application appearance and user interactions more useful will be  **Protractor** - selenium based end-to-end testing framework for angular.

Comment: According to the Angular documentation, *fixture.detectChanges() only checks for changes in terms of data binding.* It does not check for changes on the template itself. I am thinking of a bypass, except it would be kind of difficult to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Also after fixture.detectChanges() your DOM will be updated and you will have possibility to check changes in DOM.

Comment: If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650776/bootstrap-tooltip-calling-queryselector-on-the-tooltip-from-a-jasmine-karma), you'll notice I did try at least something similar to **fixture.detectChanges()** once, but it didn't work.